# How to set Crystal Report's FormulaFiled value from TextBox's form Value

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using this code to set the value of FormulaField:

```
xreport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("AllMost1").Text = 30
```

But it gives me the next Error:

[image]

Update:

This is the property panel that I take the name from:

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the property panel of the formula field placed on the report canvas? If so, the answer is NO.  You need to simply use the formula name.

Based on the new image you posted, you are indeed using the wrong name. You need to use the name of the formula, not the name of the formula field placed on the report canvas. Most likely, you need to drop the '1' at the end of the name. So change to:

```
xreport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("AllMost").Text = Chr(39) & 30 & Chr(39)
```

Comment: I updated the post and shared the image of property

Answer (score 0):

The formula text must be text rather than a number. So test something like:

```
xreport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("AllMost1").Text = Chr(39) & 30 & Chr(39)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is with the reference to the formula name. Make sure it is indeed "AllMost1".

Comment: I'm using the name that appears in the property panel, is that right?

Comment: please if you have any help provide me, this error makes me crazy